# extracting array from bigger associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have stored many arrays in a single associative array and assigned key values simple number counting.

How can I extract one of those array from the associative array?

my array:

```
$arr = array(
        1 => array("ask","bat","cod","dig","egg","fur","gap","hay","ice","jar","kin","lee"), 
        2 => array("add","big","cap","day","eye","fat","gel","hop","ink","jog","key","law"),   
        3 => array("axe","bin","cel","don","eat","fig","gig","hut","ion","jin","kid","lip")
    );
```

I want to store the array indexed say 2 in `$arr_chosen`, what will be the syntax to do so?

Comment: `$arr_chosen=$arr[2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
        1 => array("ask","bat","cod","dig","egg","fur","gap","hay","ice","jar","kin","lee"), 
        2 => array("add","big","cap","day","eye","fat","gel","hop","ink","jog","key","law"),   
        3 => array("axe","bin","cel","don","eat","fig","gig","hut","ion","jin","kid","lip")
    );
$arr_chosen = $arr[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract an array by doing

```
$arr_chosen = $arr[2]
```